# how to test mail() using PHPUnit

Tags: php, unit-testing, email, testing, phpunit

is there a way to test with PHPUnit (or maybe other testing framework for PHP) if mail is sent correctly? I have to test a code which uses PHP function mail() . With custom mailer class i could always make a mock, but for mail() ... ? Maybe there is some plugin which is capable to use IMAP and verify if mail is received? (and it should be OS-agnostic if it is possible...)

Answer (score 8):

The solution here would be to wrap mail in a class that could be mocked and use that instead.

I don't see the point in testing `mail()` itself, I'm sure it's been thoroughly tested already.

Comment: my problem is that mail() is only part of larger method

Comment: @ts Artefacto's point still stands: The best idea would be to set up a wrapper class that can mock `mail()` in the unit test (and, say, always return `true` unless the recipient E-Mail address is not a valid one.)

Answer (score 2):

There is a project called MailCatcher that can help assure you your email has (a) been sent and (b) is constructed as intended (it has the content you put into it).
Note this program does not verify that your email is receivable (ie: not marked as spam or rejected by a mail server for other reasons)

Mailcatcher is a local SMTP service and web interface to help you verify emails sent by your code. In addition, emails can be programmatically verified by using the API: eg: /messages, /messages/:id.json, /messages/:id.html etc.
To use the API you'll need something like Guzzle to make the HTTP calls.
The project page is http://mailcatcher.me/

A nice tutorial with links to example code: http://codeception.com/12-15-2013/testing-emails-in-php.html

Answer (score -5):

> is there a way to test with PHPUnit
>   (or maybe other testing framework for
>   PHP) if mail is sent correctly?

*If you want to check whether or not mail was sent successfully*, you don't need phpunit, you simply do:

```
mail(.....) or die('Could not send the email !!');
```

Or

```
if (!mail(......)){
  echo 'Could not send the email !!';
}
```

***Note*** that this tells you whether or not mail was sent NOT whether or not it was received to whom the email was sent. So the better term here should be ***delivered***.

Comment: Right on, because the only failure you can reliably detect is the local delivery failure. Checking if it has been received in an inbox can fail for myriad reasons.

Comment: it is not for check if mail was sent or not. it's for unit testing - i need to know not only if mail was sent (no problem as i pass return of mail() ), but also if it was well formed (headers, content, attachements etc) and delivered to proper account)

Comment: @ts I'm not really sure whether this is suitable for unit testing - they are so many things that could go wrong depending on the server setup. I'd say this calls for a mock.

Comment: i agree, but mocking native php functions is quite beyond me now ;)

Comment: @ts: Also as @Artefacto pointed out, `mail` is already thoroughly checked. You may be interested in SwiftMailer for example then.

Comment: At present, Mailgun is free for up to 10,000 messages per month.  It will let you look at the log for a lot of information about your mail delivery. It's likely that Mailgun, or some other service, will also give you better deliverability for your email messages unless you have already implemented DKIM and SPF capability for mail().